# Push object value into array as separate items

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to add all the pink values of the objects below to the pink array as items.

```
const mainObj = [
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "green",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "green",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "blue",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "blue",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "green",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
}
];
```

What i have so far:

```
for(let i = 0; i < mainObj.length; i++) {
    if(mainObj[i].colour == "pink") {
        const pink = [];
        pink.push(mainObj[i].colour);   
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that at the moment it's not pushing all the pink values in one pink array but it individually creates a pink array and adds one to each.

Comment: Why are you pushing just `.colour`? That will just be "pink" and seems pretty useless…

Comment: @Alinacdn you didn't get his point, he is telling it will output a array of string `"pink"` which is a guessable answer and is not a evaluated answer based on input array. the only thing is useful in the output is the length of your array denoting the number of objects having pink color.

Comment: I just wanted to do this as an exercise, but actually you guys have a point. I only need to check the times pink occurs really. Obviously there is no point to have an array with pink but just wanted to know how can this be achieved.

Comment: @Alinacdn But you could re-create an array of other objects ( and specific fields) that were pink.

Comment: Yes, I've seen your solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Alinacdn the questions actually looks look like you  need the items having color pink. so in case you need only count you can take the `length` of the output array from any of the valid answers

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee well yes I think I've put the wrong question and had the wrong approach. Thank you all for your help. I think it's all more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

### Basic

You can do this using the filter method, which will automatically create an array with the values you want.

```
let pinkArray = ;
console.log(pinkArray);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1pjh56a3/2/

### Specific Values/Columns

You could also create an array with only specific fields in the objects:

```
 let pinkArray = mainObj.filter( e =>  e.colour == 'pink');
console.log(pinkArray);

var pinkArrayCopy = [];
for(i in pinkArray){
        let item = pinkArray[i];
    pinkArrayCopy.push({"colour": item.colour, "text": item.text});
 }

console.log(pinkArrayCopy);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1pjh56a3/6/

### And even more functional ( new objects)

```
 let pinkArray = mainObj.filter( e =>  e.colour == 'pink').map( 
 j =>  {
                    return {"a": j.colour, "b": j.text}; 
            }
 );

console.log(pinkArray);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1pjh56a3/16/

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it. Simply put the `const pink = [];` outside your for loop like so (I've also changed the `push` to be the object rather than just the color)

```
let pink = [];
for(let i = 0; i < mainObj.length; i++) {
    if(mainObj[i].colour == "pink") {
        pink.push(mainObj[i]);   
    }
}
```

Here is a working example:

```js
const mainObj = [
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "green",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "green",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "blue",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "blue",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "green",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
}
];

let pink = [];
for(let i = 0; i < mainObj.length; i++) {
    if(mainObj[i].colour == "pink") {
        pink.push(mainObj[i]);   
    }
}

console.log(pink)
```

This will make it so that it doesn't create a `pink` array at every iteration of your for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a call back passing the main array and colour, and simply filter the main array with the given colour.

```js
const mainArr = [{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
  },
  {
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
  },
  {
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
  },
  {
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
  },
  {
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "green",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
  },
  {
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "green",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
  }
],
filterByColor = (arr, colour) =>arr.filter(a=>a.colour===colour);

var pink = filterByColor(mainArr, 'pink'),
    green = filterByColor(mainArr, 'green');

console.log('Pink: ', pink);
console.log('Green: ', green);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```js
const mainObj = [
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "pink",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "green",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "green",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "blue",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "blue",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
},
{
    image: 'test_icon.jpg',
    colour: "green",
    text: "text",
    link: ""
}
];

let pink = mainObj.filter(item => {
if (item.colour === 'pink') {
 return item.colour;
  }
}).map(item => item.colour);

console.log(pink)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
mainObj.filter(item => item.colour=='pink').map(i =>i.colour))
```